# mocking nested server response

Tags: json, mockito, kotlin

I have the following Json models:

```
/**
 * Json model of room response
 */
open class JsonRoom(val BookingData: JsonRoomBookingData,
                    val GeneralData: JsonRoomGeneralData)

/**
 * Json model of room booking data
 */
open class JsonRoomBookingData(val BookingId: Int,
                               val BookingStatus: Int,
                               val RoomId: Int,
                               val RoomName: String,
                               val TimeFrom: Date,
                               val TimeTo: Date,
                               val TimeFromUtc: Date,
                               val TimeToUtc: Date,
                               val Isrecurrence: Boolean,
                               val RecurrenceID: Boolean,
                               val BookingSource: Int,
                               val IsMultiRoom: Boolean,
                               val canBeStarted: Boolean,
                               val canBeClosed: Boolean,
                               val canBeExtended: Boolean)

/**
 * Json model of room general data
 */
open class JsonRoomGeneralData(val CountryID: Int,
                               val FloorID: Int,
                               val FloorNum: Int,
                               val LocationID: Int,
                               val MeetingTitle: String,
                               val NumAttending: Int)
```

and the following code in one of my tests is failing:

```
// Arrange
// Setup room mock
val roomBookingDataMock = Mockito.mock(JsonRoomBookingData::class.java)
val roomGeneralDataMock = Mockito.mock(JsonRoomGeneralData::class.java)
val roomMock = Mockito.mock(JsonRoom::class.java)
Mockito.`when`(roomMock.BookingData)
        .thenReturn(roomBookingDataMock)
```

In particular on the line `Mockito.`when`(roomMock.BookingData)` with exception:

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

Am I missing something, is this a Kotlin problem as it wraps up Java's getter/setters? Do I need to annotate my Json model properties with some annotation I don't know about?

Comment: I came across this:

https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/issues/61

Saying that you need to make the properties open to extension, which just sounds... horrible. It works... but really?

Comment: These are just data classes, why mock them and not instantiate 'real' objects?

Comment: Mocking is for testing the behaviour of the mocked object. You should not be testing the behaviour of the JsonRoom class, since it has no logic that you need to test. This isn't a suitable thing to mock.

Comment: Yea thanks, think I was a bit tired...